# How to disable Phantom?

Tags: xcom-2

My sharpshooter just got the Phantom "ability" via the Advanced Warfare Center.   This is completely useless (why would I ever scout with a sniper?) and means he can't participate in ambushes.

How do I turn it off or get rid of it altogether?

Comment: You can try to respec the character in the AWC but otherwise the abilities aren't things you can disable/remove specifically from characters.

Comment: I thought i might like that perk for a ranger as well, but losing out on ambush was worse than occasionally keeping concealed. My only solution was to make that ranger instigate confrontations, and keep everyone else in overwatch. Respec seems to be the only other option.

Comment: @n_palum: Respeccing doesn't reroll the AWC perk. I still turned him into a gunslinger, Phantom works better with that build.

Comment: Your can set your sniper to overwatch and they'll still participate in an ambush, and overwatch from ambush has none of the usual overwatch aim penalties.  This can get ridiculous with killzone.  And if it turns out he's not needed he can still maintain that bonus for the next group.  Phantom sniper is quite good imo.

Comment: When I enable Kill Zone on a concealed Phantom sniper, nothing happens. Same for regular overwatch.

Comment: that seems to be a glitch then.  When I have an enemy squad in a kill zone on my concealed sniper, he will usually take out the entire group.

Comment: An individually concealed unit will only activate overwatch when that unit's concealment is broken... so no, this unit will not participate normally in an ambush unless they're on the front lines.

Comment: I gotta say, a Phantom sniper sounds awesome to me! I usually want my sniper on high ground, which means they're not just behind my squad, they're often to one side or the other of the direction I'm advancing if that's where the good locations are. This means that they can accidentally reveal a pod on their own that's far from the rest of my squad - very dangerous! Being able to position my sniper wherever I want without being detected sounds like a definite perk.

Answer (score 6):

**There is no natural way to remove or suppress this ability.**

As you have seen, this can indeed act as a detriment.  A strategic way to work around this limitation is to use this character as the one to take the opening shot in an ambush.

Comment: There's no way to universally shut this ability off, but running through windows or doors breaks concealment - depending on the particular map layout this might be convenient.

Comment: @Josh: But it breaks concealment for **all** concealed non-phantom units. OP's sniper will never partake in the opening ambush overwatch shots unless he gets flanked (which you should avoid).

Comment: @Flater Unless the Sniper is the one who takes the initial shot.

Comment: @SouthpawHare: Yes :) Technically, I was correct already: `OP's sniper will never partake in the opening ambush *overwatch* shots` But clarifying it is still helpful :)